# The NZ() function seems not to work when called from VB, is there an alternative

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am working on an add-query.
In the add query I am trying to fill field `C` with with a true or false value, depending on the value in field `A`.
If the value in field `A` equals `-1` the value in field `C` should be `true` `(-1)`

I thought that the solution would be something like the following, but I am getting `#Error` in the results:

`C: IIf([A]='-1',True,False)`

A solution that seems to return the desired outcome is the following:
`B: IIf(Nz([A])='-1',True,False)`

[image]

The problem with this (NZ-function) is that it throws an error when running the query with VB (ADO,DAO or OLEDB)

My question is:
What formula can be used to get to the desired results without using the NZ-function
The desired results are as given in field `B`

Comment: How are you running the query in VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using quotes, I assume your value is a string. In that case, `Nz` will convert a `Null` to a zero-length string.

You can achieve the same by simply concatenating an empty string:

```
IIf([A] & ''='-1',True,False)
```

A more general solution is to use `IIf`, which allows you to specify an alternative value on nulls:

```
IIf(IIf([A] IS NULL, '', [A]) = '-1', True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As `[A]` is numeric, all you need is to compare it with `True`:

```
C: [A]=True
```

Comment: That will propagate nulls, while the OPs solution sets nulls to false.